# How to get Scala annotations that are given to an argument of a method

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Consider the following annotation:

```scala
// ok to have more meta
@field
@param
@compileTimeOnly("Only for code generation")
case class Annot(value: String) extends ConstantAnnotation
```

Now three uses:

```scala
case class A(x: Int, @Annot("z") y: String)
object A:
  def f1(x: Int, y: String @Annot("z")): A = ???
  def f2(x: Int, @Annot("z") y: String): A = ???
```

I would like to use Scala 3 macros to find each of these annotations.

1. **Case Class:** `Symbol.caseFields` gives me the list of parameters, and on each of those parameters (of type `Symbol`), method `annotations` gives me what I am looking for.
2. **Annotated Type:** Each param is a `ValDef`. If `param.tpt.tpe` matches `AnnotatedType(tpe, t)` then `t` is the annotation that I am looking for.
3. **Annotated method argument:** I HAVE NOTHING!

Any idea how I can get the annotations that are given to an argument in a method? When I print terms/symbols/trees/... I cannot even see "z" in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write in a macro

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
import scala.quoted.*

inline def printAnnotations[A]: Unit = ${printAnnotationsImpl[A]}

@experimental // because .typeRef is @experimental
def printAnnotationsImpl[A](using Quotes, Type[A]): Expr[Unit] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val symbol = TypeTree.of[A].symbol
  println(symbol.caseFields.map(_.annotations)) // Case Class

  val companion = symbol.companionModule
  val methods = companion.declaredMethods
  // Annotated method argument
  println(methods.map(_.paramSymss.map(_.map(_.annotations)))) 

  // Annotated Type
  println(methods.collect(method => companion.typeRef.memberType(method) match {
    case lt: LambdaType => lt.paramTypes.collect {
      case at: AnnotatedType => at.annotation
    }
  }))

  '{()}
}
```

Then for

```
case class A(x: Int, @Annot("z1") y: String)
object A:
  def f1(x: Int, y: String @Annot("z2")): A = ???
  def f2(x: Int, @Annot("z3") y: String): A = ???
```

`printAnnotations[A]` will print

```
List(List(), List(Apply(Select(New(Ident(Annot)),<init>),List(Literal(Constant(z1))))))

List(List(List(List(), List())), List(List(List())), List(), List(List(List(), List())), List(List(List(), List(Apply(Select(New(Ident(Annot)),<init>),List(Literal(Constant(z3))))))), List(List()), List(List(List())))

List(List(), List(), List(Apply(Select(New(Ident(Annot)),<init>),List(Literal(Constant(z2))))), List(), List(), List())
```

Scala 3.1.3

Comment: https://github.com/evolution-gaming/derivation/blob/5bff9cb72e6d68a90d3e57bbcc352103e295108d/modules/core/src/main/scala/evo/derivation/config/ConfigMacro.scala https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/expose-type-annotations-in-mirrors/5936 https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3/blob/main/modules/deriving/src/main/scala/shapeless3/deriving/annotation.scala